# Lenovo u400 cannot boot?

Tags: windows, boot, lenovo-laptop

Well i am in deep trouble. I accidentally convert my basic disk(where windows is installed ) to dynamic disk. How do i fix it back without sending to fix? Does the minitool partition thing work for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer!

**THERE ARE 3 METHODS**

***Method one***:

Go to bios and change the boot order. Move the hdd all the way up.

***Method two***:

Insert windows installation disk.

There, you can use the command prompt to clear everything in the disk before you can change

the disk from dynamic disk to basic disk.

***Method two detailed walkthough***:

Type "diskpart" and enter.

Type "list disk".

Select your disk. There is a number given to each disk. So let's say x = number given to each disk.

Type "select disk " and type in the value x.

Type "clean all".

Type "convert basic".

Note, if you fail at the last step, remove all the partitions in it!!!

Then, quit out of diskpart and cmd and choose the disk you want to install windows on.

DONE!

(If you fail, I got a little trick:

choose the disk, press the back arrow key and exit installation.

Choose to install again and you will see a new disk/ partition. The one you selected previously will become system reserve disk/partition. Anyway, select the new disk/ partition.

PROFIT!!!

***Method 3***:

Send your lenovo pc for fixing.